# get the highest version number for the id from arraylist in java

Tags: java, collections, maps, linkedhashmap

I have a arraylist which contains these values:

```
ArrayList<string,string> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.put("A101","2020_1.0");
list.put("A101","2020_3.0");
list.put("A101","2020_2.0");
list.put("A102","2020_2.0");
list.put("A102","2020_1.0");
```

I need to get:
A101 2020_3.0 and
A102 2020_2.0

Comment: It does not contain those values. Read the documentation for `Map`, especially the documentation for `put`.

Comment: now i have changed the it to arraylist now can you tell?

Answer (score 0):

First, the data container here does not appear to be a `List<String>`, it is rather a `Map<String, String>` because `List` does not have method `put(K key, V value);` while `Map` does.

However, if method `Map::put` is used, it overwrites previous values with the new ones.  So, a custom map may be implemented with the overridden method `put` (as well as `putAll`) to compare the values and keep the one with the "highest" version.

```java
class MyMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    private final Comparator<V> valueComparator;

    public MyMap(Comparator<V> valueComparator) {
        super();
        this.valueComparator = valueComparator;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return compute(key, 
            (k, v) -> v == null ? value // value missing
                                : valueComparator.compare(v, value) < 0 
                                ? value : v // keep the max of two
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        m.forEach(this::put);
    }
}
```

Assuming that in the existing examples the values can be compared as usual Strings, the map may be created as follows:

```java
// use plain String comparison
Map<String, String> data = new MyMap<>(String::compareTo);

data.put("A101", "2020_1.0");
data.put("A101", "2020_3.0");
data.put("A101", "2020_2.0");
data.put("A102", "2020_2.0");
data.put("A102", "2020_1.0");

System.out.println(data);
```

Output:

```
{A101=2020_3.0, A102=2020_2.0}
```

If the "version" values have more complex comparison rules (e.g. split to integer parts as in `9.1` and `10.0`, exclude some prefix/suffix, etc.), a custom comparator needs to be implemented.